# vis.js error in angular JS

Tags: angularjs, vis.js

I am trying to use vis.js library to visualize a simple network. My controller is as follows

```
var App = angular.module('App', ['ngRoute','ngVis']);


    App.controller('visController', ['$scope','$http','$window','VisDataSet',function($scope,$http,$window,VisDataSet)
    {
        $scope.Nodes = [];
        $scope.Edges = [];
        $http.post('/getNetworkData').success(function(response) 
        {
            $scope.Nodes = response.Nodes;
            $scope.Edges = response.Edges;
            console.log($scope.Edges);
            console.log($scope.Nodes);
        });

        var network = null;

        var destroy = function(){
            if(network!=null)
            {
                network.destroy();
                network = null;
            }    
        }

        var draw = function()
        {
            destroy();
            var nodes = new vis.Dataset($scope.Nodes);
            var edges = new vis.Dataset($scope.Edges);
            var container = angular.element( document.querySelector('#mynetwork'));
            console.log(container);
            var data = {
                nodes : nodes,
                edges : edges
            };

            var options = {
                interaction: {
                  navigationButtons: true,
                  keyboard: true
                }
            };
            network = new vis.Network(container,data,options);
            network.on('select', function(params) {
                console.log("clicked");
            });
        }
        draw();

    }]);
```

and my html div is as follows

```
     <!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Visualization Page</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Titillium+Web:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/normalize.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/style.css">
        <link href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/visualizationPage/style_vispage.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/bootstrap/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ng-file-upload-shim.min.js"></script> 
        <script src="js/ng-file-upload.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers/controller.js"></script>
        <script src="js/ngDialog.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/createNetwork/ngDialog.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/createNetwork/ngDialog-theme-default.css">
        <script src="js/vis.js"></script>
        <script src="js/exampleUtil.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap/vis.css">
        <script src="js/googleAnalytics.js"></script>
    </head>    
    <body ng-controller="visController">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-2 sidebar">
                    <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
                        <li class="active"><a href="/visualization">Visualization<span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                        <li><a href="/data">Data</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-9 col-sm-offset-3 col-md-10 col-md-offset-2 main">
                    <h2 class="page-header">Visualization</h2>
                    <div id="mynetwork">

                    </div>  
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I am getting an error `Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]` when i try to load the page. Can someone tell me what I am missing in my code.

My error is as follows

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.2/$injector/modulerr?p0=n...)
    at Error (native)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:6:416
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:40:60
    at p (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:39:304
    at p (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at db (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:43:164)
    at c (https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.2/angular.min.js:20:463
```

Comment: open console, there should be error message saying what you are missing.

Comment: I have added the error please check!

Comment: Error message contains link to some details.

Answer (score 1):

First, this is unrelated to your issue, but there are several things that should be cleaned up here.

1. Eliminate the use of success in your call to $http.post and replace it with then. Success is depracated.
2. It looks like this should be a call to $http.get, not post.
3. Draw should be called from the then method of the call to $http.get rather than at the end of your controller initialization. The way this is currently written you cannot guarantee that this call is complete and the data is available before your draw function executes.

As for the missing module, it is most likely a pathing issue, spelling issue or an issue with the order that you are loading your javascript files. That code would of course be in your html.

You're loading jquery more than once. You only need it once. When you're using angular with Jquery always load jquery first. Angular will make use of it instead of JQLite in those circumstances. I don't see anything else, but it's possible that loading JQuery after Angular and then loading it again is stepping on something.

Comment: Ok, first, you're loading jquery more than once. You only need it once. Second, when you're using angular with Jquery always load jquery first. Angular will make use of it instead of JQLite in those circumstances. I don't see anything else, but it's possible that loading JQuery after angular and then loading it again is stepping on something.

Comment: I made those changes! still not working! What all do I need to install to use the vis.js library?

Comment: I'm not even sure the issue is with vis.js. You seem to have a ton of stuff in your html that's not currently in use. I'd start by pairing it down to the bare minimum. If you step through the code do you get the error on instantation of the module or the controller? (I believe it's the module). Check the network page in your debugger and make sure all of the files are loading without error. This may simply be an issue of spelling or pathing with one of your js files.